# how to sort directory using command in window

Tags: sorting, cmd

I am trying to sort my directory using the `command prompt`.
The below command sorts the directory and display on screen, but not sorting in the actual directory:

```
C:\>dir C:\Users\ap\Desktop\pdf /o:d
```

I want to sort in the actual directory.

Comment: [edit] your question and show the result you are getting as well as the result you want to get.

Comment: Why do you think this can be done? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Using `/o:d` will sort by date ascending. What kind of sort do you want?

Answer (score 1):

The NTFS file system stores filenames in alphabetical order. This means it is fairly fast no matter how many files are in the folder. **You CANNOT change the order of files in a folder**.

Here's a brief maths answer why this is so. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm for more detail.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-fastest-algorithm-for-searching-in-ordered-lists-and-unordered-lists

> For ordered list
>   1.We can go for binary search not as been suggested by my friend Siddharth.
>   2.Ordered list allows us to go for mid term searching.
>   3.Time complexity will be O(log n) for n inputs.
>   4.(Note that log is of base 2)
>
> For unordered list
>   1.In this type of list we have to go for Linear search algo.
>   2.Binary search on Unordered list will not work.
>   3.Time complexity will be O(n) for n inputs.

**To give you an idea**

A 4 billion record sorted database will take a maximum of **32 accesses** using binary search. The same database if unsorted will take an **average of 2 billion** and a **maximum of 4 billion accesses**.